# TYPO3 11.5.30 Legacy Mode / Error after Bootstrap Update / undefined function mb_split

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

today i updated to 11.5.30 my installation to typo3 11.5.30 and Bootstrap 14.0.6.
now some pages with text content does not work anymore.

> Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Call to undefined function TYPO3\HtmlSanitizer\Serializer\mb_split() | Error thrown in file /var/www/html/typo3_src-11.5.30/vendor/typo3/html-sanitizer/src/Serializer/Rules.php in line 187.

can you help?

Comment: What have yout ried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Maybe the upgrade notes contained some requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs in the `typo3/html-sanitizer` package and was recently fixed:

- https://github.com/TYPO3/html-sanitizer/pull/110 (2.x)

This has been released with [version 2.1.3 of the package](https://github.com/TYPO3/html-sanitizer/releases/tag/v2.1.3), so you should update accordingly.

On that note: [TYPO3v12+ will require the PHP `mbstring` extension](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/12.0/Breaking-96889-RequirePHPMbstringAndIntl.html) so you can already prepare for that by making sure it is enabled.

Comment: `mbstring` is already a requirement for v11 according the docs but not in the composer.json where Symfony's polyfill is used instead.

Comment: See my comment above. The docs should be fixed accordingly. :-)

Comment: The problem is the branch 11.5 was never updated to the latest release of the sanitizer, so legacy installs still have this issue. https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/11.5/composer.lock#L5008-L5009. Will talk to Olly...

Comment: thanks - I removed line 187 in Rules.php. now it worked!

Comment: fyi https://forge.typo3.org/issues/101705

Comment: I've created a new issue https://forge.typo3.org/issues/101705 - in open-source projects anybody can create pull-requests - thx

Comment: Good hint, it is very likely that Legacy Mode is used here, I've updated the question title for discovery.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP extension `mbstring` is missing in your installation but is a requirement to properly run TYPO3 see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/11.5/en-us/SystemRequirements/Index.html#required-extensions

More information about the PHP extension and how to install it is available at https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php.

Comment: That doc page is incorrect, `mbstring` is not required for TYPO3v11, instead it is optional and `symfony/polyfill-mbstring` is used. Only with TYPO3v12 it will be mandatory.

Comment: Yes, agree, docs are wrong.